# Repeating a block of TAGs in XML using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have another query, which I tried but can't get it done...
Below is the XML Code -

```
<Main>
<Region>
<Division>
<DivName>Abc</DivName>
<Desc>BBB</Desc>
<Info></Info>
</Division>
<Division>
<DivName>Pqr</DivName>
<Desc></Desc>
<Info></Info>
</Division>
<Division>
.
.
.
</Division>
</Region>
</Main>
```

In the Division tag, DivName is compulsory, ie; it will be there, but Desc and Info are optional. Also the Division tag, which contains Desc, DivName and Info tags, could appear only once of number of times. So to display it, I must use for-each.

I also want line breaks between these tags. Till now I tried a little with failure. The HTML output, I want is

```
<b>DivName Text</b>
<p>Desc Text, if any</p>
<p>Info Text, if any</p>
<hr/>
<b>DivName Text</b>
<p>Desc Text, if any</p>
<p>Info Text, if any</p>
```

Thanks in advance..
Have a nice day
John

Comment: Good question, +1. Using template pattern matching and the default XSLT processing will help you with a much simpler and shorter solution than the one you have currently accepted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This simple transformation (no `<xsl:for-each>` and no conditionals):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Division[position() >1]">
     <hr />
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Division/*[text()]">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<Main>
    <Region>
        <Division>
            <DivName>Abc</DivName>
            <Desc>BBB</Desc>
            <Info>More info abour Abc</Info>
        </Division>
        <Division>
            <DivName>Pqr</DivName>
            <Desc>Pqr desc.</Desc>
            <Info>More info abour Pqr</Info>
        </Division>
    </Region>
</Main>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<p>Abc</p>
<p>BBB</p>
<p>More info abour Abc</p>
<hr/>
<p>Pqr</p>
<p>Pqr desc.</p>
<p>More info abour Pqr</p>
```

**And it is displayed by the browser as**:

Abc

BBB

More info abour Abc

---

Pqr

Pqr desc.

More info abour Pqr

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Division">
  <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
  <hr/>
  </xsl:if>
  <p><xsl:value-of select="DivName" /></p>
  <xsl:if test="Desc">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="Desc"/></p>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="Info">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="Info"/></p>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: -M.L. - Thanks a lot. It worked like anything. :) Have a nice day -John